# How do I declare variable in my data class to accept value( josondata ) of countryInfo:

Tags: android, kotlin

```
data class Country (
    val country:String,
    val cases:Int,
    val todayCases:Int,
    val deaths:Int,
    val todayDeaths:Int,
    val recovered:Int,
    val todayRecovered:Int,
    val continent:String
)
```

this is  my json

```
[
    {
        "updated": 1597730495700,
        "country": "Afghanistan",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 4,
            "iso2": "AF",
            "iso3": "AFG",
            "lat": 33,
            "long": 65,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/af.png"
        },
        "cases": 37599,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 1375,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 27166,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 9058,
        "critical": 31,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 963,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 35,
        "tests": 98772,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 2530,
        "population": 39035860,
        "continent": "Asia",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 1038,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 28390,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 395,
        "activePerOneMillion": 232.04,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 695.92,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0.79
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495740,
        "country": "Albania",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 8,
            "iso2": "AL",
            "iso3": "ALB",
            "lat": 41,
            "long": 20,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/al.png"
        },
        "cases": 7499,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 230,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 3816,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 3453,
        "critical": 15,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 2606,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 80,
        "tests": 46529,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 16171,
        "population": 2877376,
        "continent": "Europe",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 384,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 12510,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 62,
        "activePerOneMillion": 1200.05,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 1326.21,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 5.21
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495698,
        "country": "Algeria",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 12,
            "iso2": "DZ",
            "iso3": "DZA",
            "lat": 28,
            "long": 3,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/dz.png"
        },
        "cases": 39025,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 1379,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 27347,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 10299,
        "critical": 40,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 888,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 31,
        "tests": 0,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 0,
        "population": 43949908,
        "continent": "Africa",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 1126,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 31871,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 0,
        "activePerOneMillion": 234.33,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 622.23,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0.91
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495806,
        "country": "Andorra",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 20,
            "iso2": "AD",
            "iso3": "AND",
            "lat": 42.5,
            "long": 1.6,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/ad.png"
        },
        "cases": 1005,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 53,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 869,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 83,
        "critical": 1,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 13004,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 686,
        "tests": 3750,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 48524,
        "population": 77281,
        "continent": "Europe",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 77,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 1458,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 21,
        "activePerOneMillion": 1074,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 11244.68,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 12.94
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495789,
        "country": "Angola",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 24,
            "iso2": "AO",
            "iso3": "AGO",
            "lat": -12.5,
            "long": 18.5,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/ao.png"
        },
        "cases": 1935,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 88,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 632,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 1215,
        "critical": 24,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 59,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 3,
        "tests": 64747,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 1963,
        "population": 32987172,
        "continent": "Africa",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 17048,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 374854,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 509,
        "activePerOneMillion": 36.83,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 19.16,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0.73
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495863,
        "country": "Anguilla",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 660,
            "iso2": "AI",
            "iso3": "AIA",
            "lat": 18.25,
            "long": -63.1667,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/ai.png"
        },
        "cases": 3,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 0,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 3,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 0,
        "critical": 0,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 200,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 0,
        "tests": 662,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 44075,
        "population": 15020,
        "continent": "North America",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 5007,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 0,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 23,
        "activePerOneMillion": 0,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 199.73,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495844,
        "country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 28,
            "iso2": "AG",
            "iso3": "ATG",
            "lat": 17.05,
            "long": -61.8,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/ag.png"
        },
        "cases": 93,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 3,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 88,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 2,
        "critical": 1,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 949,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 31,
        "tests": 1602,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 16341,
        "population": 98034,
        "continent": "North America",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 1054,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 32678,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 61,
        "activePerOneMillion": 20.4,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 897.65,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 10.2
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495646,
        "country": "Argentina",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 32,
            "iso2": "AR",
            "iso3": "ARG",
            "lat": -34,
            "long": -64,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/ar.png"
        },
        "cases": 299126,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 5814,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 217850,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 75462,
        "critical": 1749,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 6611,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 128,
        "tests": 966926,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 21369,
        "population": 45249337,
        "continent": "South America",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 151,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 7783,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 47,
        "activePerOneMillion": 1667.69,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 4814.44,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 38.65
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495697,
        "country": "Armenia",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 51,
            "iso2": "AM",
            "iso3": "ARM",
            "lat": 40,
            "long": 45,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/am.png"
        },
        "cases": 41701,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 824,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 34655,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 6222,
        "critical": 0,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 14069,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 278,
        "tests": 185594,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 62617,
        "population": 2963977,
        "continent": "Asia",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 71,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 3597,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 16,
        "activePerOneMillion": 2099.21,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 11692.06,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495806,
        "country": "Aruba",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 533,
            "iso2": "AW",
            "iso3": "ABW",
            "lat": 12.5,
            "long": -69.9667,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/aw.png"
        },
        "cases": 1121,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 4,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 212,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 905,
        "critical": 0,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 10494,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 37,
        "tests": 16261,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 152219,
        "population": 106826,
        "continent": "North America",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 95,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 26707,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 7,
        "activePerOneMillion": 8471.72,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 1984.54,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495711,
        "country": "Australia",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 36,
            "iso2": "AU",
            "iso3": "AUS",
            "lat": -27,
            "long": 133,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/au.png"
        },
        "cases": 23772,
        "todayCases": 213,
        "deaths": 438,
        "todayDeaths": 17,
        "recovered": 14539,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 8795,
        "critical": 52,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 931,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 17,
        "tests": 5375254,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 210483,
        "population": 25537753,
        "continent": "Australia/Oceania",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 1074,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 58305,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 5,
        "activePerOneMillion": 344.39,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 569.31,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 2.04
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495712,
        "country": "Austria",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 40,
            "iso2": "AT",
            "iso3": "AUT",
            "lat": 47.3333,
            "long": 13.3333,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/at.png"
        },
        "cases": 23534,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 729,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 20765,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 2040,
        "critical": 23,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 2611,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 81,
        "tests": 1024067,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 113620,
        "population": 9013119,
        "continent": "Europe",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 383,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 12364,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 9,
        "activePerOneMillion": 226.34,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 2303.86,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 2.55
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495703,
        "country": "Azerbaijan",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 31,
            "iso2": "AZ",
            "iso3": "AZE",
            "lat": 40.5,
            "long": 47.5,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/az.png"
        },
        "cases": 34343,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 508,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 32042,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 1793,
        "critical": 0,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 3383,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 50,
        "tests": 836908,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 82446,
        "population": 10150987,
        "continent": "Asia",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 296,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 19982,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 12,
        "activePerOneMillion": 176.63,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 3156.54,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 0
    },
    {
        "updated": 1597730495799,
        "country": "Bahamas",
        "countryInfo": {
            "_id": 44,
            "iso2": "BS",
            "iso3": "BHS",
            "lat": 24.25,
            "long": -76,
            "flag": "https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/bs.png"
        },
        "cases": 1329,
        "todayCases": 0,
        "deaths": 19,
        "todayDeaths": 0,
        "recovered": 191,
        "todayRecovered": 0,
        "active": 1119,
        "critical": 1,
        "casesPerOneMillion": 3375,
        "deathsPerOneMillion": 48,
        "tests": 7690,
        "testsPerOneMillion": 19531,
        "population": 393729,
        "continent": "North America",
        "oneCasePerPeople": 296,
        "oneDeathPerPeople": 20723,
        "oneTestPerPeople": 51,
        "activePerOneMillion": 2842.06,
        "recoveredPerOneMillion": 485.11,
        "criticalPerOneMillion": 2.54
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Country (
    val country:String,
    val cases:Int,
    val todayCases:Int,
    val deaths:Int,
    val todayDeaths:Int,
    val recovered:Int,
    val todayRecovered:Int,
    val continent:String,
    val countryInfo: CountryInfo
) {
    data class CountryInfo (
        val _id: Int,
        val iso2: String,
        ...
    )
}
```

You can try this.